# Gmail contacts api access error

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

I want access client gmail contacts using gmail api. but it give error like "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://" from accessing a frame with origin "https://accounts.google.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of http", the frame being accessed .
my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function auth() {
            var config = {
                'client_id': 'ID',
                'scope': 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
            };
            gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
                fetch(gapi.auth.getToken());
            });
        }
        function fetch(token) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: token
            }).done(function(data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="auth();">GET CONTACTS FEED</button>
</body>
```

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and i try to convert my apache server in https model for seeing this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X09cT8n2KeE but till i have same error.

Comment: have you configured the URL of your app (NB NOT localhost) in the API Console?

Comment: I configure API console in my system local IP.